# sed -i scripting a json file

Tags: json, shell, sed

I am trying to add { "index" : {} }\n to a json file using sed scripting.

```
sed -e 's/^/{ "index" : {} }\n/' -i 
/Users/p2s/Desktop/untitled_folder/sku.json
```

But I get an error as

```
sed: -i may not be used with stdin
```

Can anybody tell me what is the error and how to solve this?

Comment: don't parse json with sed and alike. Post your `sku.json` content

Comment: `sed -i '...' file`  read man page, where to put the options.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i -e 's/^/{ "index" : {} }\n/' /Users/p2s/Desktop/untitled_folder/sku.json
```

should do the work